# Referencing different buttons in cell on IBAction

Tags: swift, uitableview

When a button is clicked (thats located inside the cell of a tableview), I pass a reference to it to another class. However, along with it I also want to pass a reference to another button in the same cell. I can easily reference the clicked button as "sender", but how would I reference the other button in the same cell?

This is in the cell subclass, not the main view controller.

```
class ImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var upVote: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var downVote: UIButton!


    @IBAction func upVote(sender: AnyObject) {
            self.delegate?.controller(self,  button: sender as! UIButton, other: *REFERENCE DOWNVOTE BUTTON HERE*, selectedButtonIndexPath: indexPath!)

        }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Sorry, but it smell bad.. explain better your difficult! Do you need pass button reference to other cell in your table view? Why?

Comment: You have to reference the indexpath of the cell. Referencing just the iboutlet won't work

Comment: @ViTUu see the change I made to the op. Where it says *REFERENCE ..* I need to reference the downvote button in that SPECIFIC cell

Comment: ok, I understand it, just do `self.delegate?.controller(self,  button: sender as! UIButton, other: downVote, selectedButtonIndexPath: indexPath!)` but why you need send this reference? In UITableViewCell recycle self cells, because this I just want know what is your mission with this.. Maybe we can mind other solution.. Sorry, but we need know more to help your question.

Answer (score 0):

The cell has a property for each button.

Since it appears that you have separate action methods for each button, the other button is known to you and you can pass it directly:

```
@IBAction func upVote(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.delegate?.controller(self,  button: sender as! UIButton, other: downVote, selectedButtonIndexPath: indexPath!)
}
```

If you don't know which button is which, you can determine the opposite button by

```
let other = sender === self.upVote ? self.downVote : self.upVote
```